# Over wildfly-maven-plugin - JBoss DB driver connection addition using maven command failing

Tags: oracle, maven, jboss, jboss-cli, wildfly-maven-plugin

We are using `wildfly-maven-plugin` configured in `pom.xml`. Over that we are trying to install Oracle DB Driver and trying to configure DB Connection Pool in JBoss subsystem.

Please find the `pom.xml` configuration for `wildfly-maven-plugin`

```
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <hostname>${jboss_host}</hostname>
                            <port>${jboss_port}</port>
                             </configuration>
                        
                        <executions>
                        
                            <!-- Run CLI-scripts -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>jboss-config</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <execute-commands>
                                        <scripts>                                           
                                            <script>${basedir}/target/jboss/configuration/jboss-all-script.cli</script>
                                        </scripts>
                                    </execute-commands>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Following command installs Oracle DB driver sucessfully.

```
mvn clean install -Pdeploy-oracle-driver,localdev
```

Following command supposed to configure DB Driver Connection but it is failing. Here is the mvn command and the concerned error output.

```
mvn clean install -Pjboss,localdev
```

Error,

```
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.2.Final:execute-commands (jboss-config) @ csd-servers-jboss ---
WARN: can't find jboss-cli.xml. Using default configuration values.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.382 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-24T15:14:02+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.2.Final:execute-commands (jboss-config) on project csd-servers-jboss: Execution jboss-config of goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.2.Final:execute-commands failed: Failed to initialize CLI context: Failed to initialize Aesh console: org/fusesource/jansi/WindowsAnsiOutputStream: org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

And we have the following file - `cli-filters-localdev.properties` under `jboss` folder in the maven project.

> spring_profiles_active=localdev logging_level=DEBUG
> oracle_deploy_name=oracle_driver
> ds_tx_name=${project.parent.artifactId}_db
> ds_tx_jndi=java:jboss/jdbc/${project.parent.artifactId}/DataSource
> ds_no_tx_name=${project.parent.artifactId}_db_NoTx
> ds_no_tx_jndi=java:jboss/jdbc/${project.parent.artifactId}/DataSource_NoTx
> database_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//srv251.srv.pulp.com:11523/jeevee.srv.pulp.com
> database_server=srv251.srv.pulp.com database_port=11523
> database_name=jeevee database_user=bul database_password=showbot
> database_max_pool_size=20 database_timeout=5000

what is wrong that I am doing over here, why this `mvn` command is failing,- `mvn clean install -Pjboss,localdev`

I understood this is basically happening through `jboss-cli` - JBoss Command Line Interface - `Aesh console`

Comment: Adding the `-e` maven switch might give you some hints for the actual problem. I would guess that it fails to authenticate with the server

Comment: Definitely looks like a strange error. You could try upgrading to 2.0.2.Final. If that doesn't work keep on 2.0.2.Final, but add `<fork>true</fork>` to your configuration.

Comment: When I am using `2.0.2.Final` build is succeeding, however, it is not adding `db driver connection` in `JBoss EAP subsystem`. And for the moment I cannot go beyond `1.2.2.Final` due to my project constraint. Maybe someone can let me know what have been went wrong in the `wildfly-maven-plugin` with the present configuration.